# ReactNative android app working very slower, can any one help me to solve?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on reactnative android app , and recently my app started to work very slower , i dont know whats happening in background! ,
please help me whether it is related with navigator or someother issues.

Comment: Have you tried reading this part of the documentation? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html

Answer (score 0):

Check [React Native Performance](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html) and if you use push on transitions and you think its not really needed just do .replace() instead it helped me alot with the smoothness